# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -larmpl_lp64: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, gfortran, lapack

I was trying to compile a program dependent on LAPACK. During compilation this error message popped up:

```
FAILED: /home/parallels/qp2/src/basis_correction/basis_correction 
gfortran -g -ffree-line-length-none -I . -fPIC -march=native -fopenmp -I ao_basis/ -I ao_one_e_ints/ -I ao_two_e_erf_ints/ -I ao_two_e_ints/ -I aux_quantities/ -I basis/ -I becke_numerical_grid/ -I bitmask/ -I cas_based_on_top/ -I csf/ -I davidson/ -I davidson_undressed/ -I density_for_dft/ -I determinants/ -I dft_keywords/ -I dft_one_e/ -I dft_utils_func/ -I dft_utils_in_r/ -I electrons/ -I ezfio_files/ -I functionals/ -I mo_basis/ -I mo_one_e_ints/ -I mo_two_e_erf_ints/ -I mo_two_e_ints/ -I mpi/ -I mu_of_r/ -I nuclei/ -I pseudo/ -I two_body_rdm/ -I two_rdm_routines/ -I utils/ -I zmq/ /home/parallels/qp2/src/basis_correction/IRPF90_temp/basis_correction.irp.o /home/parallels/qp2/src/basis_correction/IRPF90_temp/basis_correction.irp.module.o /home/parallels/qp2/src/basis_correction/IRPF90_temp/irpf90.a -larmpl_lp64 /home/parallels/qp2/lib/libezfio_irp.a /home/parallels/qp2/lib/libf77zmq.a /home/parallels/qp2/lib/libzmq.a -lstdc++ -lrt -ldl -lz -o /home/parallels/qp2/src/basis_correction/basis_correction
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -larmpl_lp64: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I then went on installing the ArmPL from [here](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-performance-libraries) and retried compilation, but the same error message popped up. In the config .cfg file I saw a line reading

```
LAPACK_LIB   : -larmpl_lp64
```

I browsed the ArmPL directory containing files with similar names corresponding to that, but I am not sure what it is asking for.

Comment: Are you on an ARM CPU computer? Which CPU architecture do you use? What CPU and OS is your program (or its Makefile) written for? To see what  LP64 means, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: The flag `-larmpl_lp64` means it's looking for a file called `libarmpl_lp64.a`.   It will search in all the directories specified on the `ld` command line with a `-L` prefix